# My method of retrieving Git tag information in Node JS is slow, how can I speed it up?

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, node-modules

I'm creating a Node JS script that needs to get all Git tags from the repository, along with the message and date the tag was created, and then save them as a entries in a JSON file. For example:

```
[{
  "tag": "v1.1.0",
  "message": "Add navigation",
  "date": "Tue Oct 4 10:19:12 2018 +0100"
}, {
  "tag": "v1.1.1",
  "message": "Fix issue with spacing in the navigation",
  "date": "Tue Oct 9 12:13:16 2018 +0100"
}]
```

I've figured out how to do it, using some Node modules to access the tags, and then execute some Git commands to get all the information I need from each tag. This is done using [shelljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shelljs).

The problem I have is that this is very slow. Running `gitTag.all((tags) = {})` (using [git-tag](https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-tag)) is fast, because it just pulls in the tag names. However, to get the message and date, I'm running two separate commands for each tag within a loop:

```
let msg = shell.exec(`git for-each-ref refs/tags/${tag} --format='%(subject)'`, {silent:true}).stdout;
let date = shell.exec(`git for-each-ref refs/tags/${tag} --format='%(authordate)'`, {silent:true}).stdout;
```

Both of these commands are a little slow anyway, but running them every time for each tag name takes a long while.

**Is there a quicker way for me to do this?**

Please bare in mind that I'm running this synchronously, because another Node script will be reading this JSON file, and it may cause a race conidtion. However any asynchronous ideas are welcome if they can also address that.

Please see my **full code below**:

```
const gitTag = require('git-tag')({
  localOnly: true,
  dir: '.git'
});
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const shell = require('shelljs');

let tagsAllData = [];

let formatString = (string) => {
  return string.replace(/^'/, '').replace(/'\n+$/, '');
}

// Fetch all git tags
gitTag.all((tags) => {
  tags.forEach(tag => {

    // Collect the tag message and date values
    let msg = shell.exec(`git for-each-ref refs/tags/${tag} --format='%(subject)'`, {silent:true}).stdout;
    let date = shell.exec(`git for-each-ref refs/tags/${tag} --format='%(authordate)'`, {silent:true}).stdout;

    // Create array of tag objects
    tagsAllData.push({
      'tag': tag,
      'message': formatString(msg),
      'date': formatString(date)
    });
  });

  // Write the tag data as a JSON file
  let tagsJSON = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tagsAllData));
  fs.writeJSONSync('src/data/tags.json', tagsJSON);
});
```

Comment: That `shell` function is depends on the system dude. It will send the request to the system shell then get response from shell. That's it, To get results quickly, The shell need to respond quickly, then only your `nodeJS` will show the response. You can execute other functions without waiting. But to speed up this `shell` function. your system should perform well.

Comment: Thanks @BanujanBalendrakumar, I agree - this is partly why I asked the question. I'm hoping that there is a quicker way to do it, which perhaps doesn't rely on the system, or uses fewer executions. Perhaps there is another way of getting this same information which is more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your actual code calls the shell twice for each tag. To speed things up you should call the shell and hence git at most once - for *all* tags. In a shell this looks like this:

```
git for-each-ref --sort=v:refname --format "tag: %(refname:strip=2) message: %(subject) date: %(creatordate:iso)" refs/tags
```

the output looks like this:

```
tag: v2.20.0-rc0 message: Git 2.20-rc0 date: 2018-11-18 18:25:38 +0900
tag: v2.20.0-rc1 message: Git 2.20-rc1 date: 2018-11-21 23:25:15 +0900
tag: v2.20.0-rc2 message: Git 2.20-rc2 date: 2018-12-01 21:45:08 +0900
tag: v2.20.1 message: Git 2.20.1 date: 2018-12-15 12:31:46 +0900
```

You must split this output first into separate lines and each line into the fields. You can make this much easier by adjusting the `format` in a way which makes parsing easier (e.g. by using special characters between the fields).

Answer (score 1):

Building on that other answer I would also consider making the whole approach more async. `foreach` is blocking and will depend on the individual outcome of each call.

Instead, I would go with native API and create a promise out of it (as explained [here](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)).

You can the use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to aggregate the results. This is a simplified example doing

```
const dateQueries = [];
const msgQueries = [];

tags.forEach(tag => {
    const dateQuery = exec(`git for-each-ref refs/tags/${tag} --format='%(subject)'`);
    const msgQuery = exec(`git for-each-ref refs/tags/${tag} --format='%(authordate)'`);

    dateQueries.push(dateQuery);
    msgQueries.push(msgQuery);
});
const msgResults = await Promise.all(msgQueries);
const dateResults = await Promise.all(dateQueries);
```

However, A.H.'s answer is the more performant one since it optimises the query itself.